# I am trying to use Zustand, but I'm getting an error

Tags: reactjs

```js
import { create } from 'zustand';
import { mountStoreDevtools } from 'simple-zustand-devtools';

const useAuthStore = create((set, get) =>({
    allUserData: null,
    loading: false,

    user: () => ({
        user_id: get().allUserData?.user_id || null,
        username: get().allUserData?.username || null,

    }),

    setUser: (user) => set({ allUserData: user}),
    setLoading: (loading) => set({loading }),
    isLoggedIn: () => get().allUserData !== null,
}))

if (import.meta.env.DEV){
    mountStoreDevtools(useAuthStore, 'AuthStore');
}

export default { useAuthStore}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/simple-zustand-devtools.js?v=0062664c' does not provide an export named 'mountStoreDevtools' (at auth.js:2:10)

Comment: There is most likely a typo. You should import `mountStoreDevtool` instead of `mountStoreDevtools` *(There is an extra "s" at the end of your version)*.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a typo in your import, see https://github.com/beerose/simple-zustand-devtools?tab=readme-ov-file#usage

```
import { mountStoreDevtool } from 'simple-zustand-devtools';
```